# Import a SCSS file that has relative path

Tags: css, sass

I have troubles in including `_fonts.scss` inside `main.scss` files with `@use`.

As you see `_fonts.scss` contains `src` to a font which is relative to itself.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: font;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("font.woff") format("woff");
}
```

But when the `main.scss` file includes the `_fonts.scss`, the path becomes ambiguous, because there is no `font.woff` relative to `main.scss`.

```
Project_folder/
              fonts/
                   ---  _fonts.scss    
                   ---  font.woff
              page1/
                   ---  index.html
                   ---  main.scss
              category/
                       page2/
                            --- index.html
                            --- main.scss
                       page3/
                            --- index.html
                            --- main.scss
```

Since I have several web pages and they have different paths, changing the `src` path does not work for all of them at the same time.

I have also changed `_fonts.scss` to `fonts.css` and used `@import`. It did not work either.

Can you suggest me an approach to keep it simple and working? (I cannot change the project structure tree)

Comment: You need to write it from the perspective of wherever your main compiled css file is located; that's what the website will read, not the sass files.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem! As I have multiple pages, I cannot write it from the perspective of all of them. I need a unique addressing pattern that works for every page, no matter where it is. I want to just import the `fonts.scss` and it automatically finds the font.
@MattHamer5